# Convert Char array to String array

Tags: java, arrays, converters

In my following code, I convert a string array to a char array to alter the characters.

```
char[][] currentGuessArray = new char[currentGuessPhrase.length][];
for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessPhrase.length; x++) {
    currentGuessArray[x] = currentGuessPhrase[x].toCharArray();
}
for (int x = 0; x < correctPhrase.length; x++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < correctPhrase[x].length(); x++) {
        if (correctPhrase[x].charAt(a) == guess) {
            currentGuessArray[x][a] = guess;
        }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < currentGuessArray[x].length; x++){
    currentGuessPhrase[x] = currentGuessArray[x].toString();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to alter the code.

The string array contains random words like:
"fire", "golden", "illegal", etc.

Edit: Here is an example run:

```
miracles
horrible
illegal
horrible
good
```

Those are the Strings stored in `currentPhrase[]`

Input:
a

Expected output:

```
___a____ ________ _____a_ ________ ____
```

Actual output:

```
[C@5265a77f [C@fd7ad1c [C@18a61164 [C@3ebfc8e0 ____
```

Comment: why are you using a 2d array for currentGuessArray? Are you getting errors? Show your expected and actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change

```
currentGuessPhrase[x] = currentGuessArray[x].toString();
```

to

```
currentGuessPhrase[x] = new String(currentGuessArray[x]);
```